# SQLite3 using another hard drive for creating index

Tags: database, indexing, sqlite

I have two hard disks: ***C*** (40GB capacity left) and ***D*** (1TB capacity left).

My ***sqlite folder*** (SQLite3 Windows download files from tutorial) is in disk D.

I created a database called ***myDatabase.db*** in the sqlite folder and have created a table in it and populated the table from a CSV file. This was done successfully as I ran a few queries and they worked.

The size of the database is quite large (50GB) and I want to create an index for my table. I do the CREATE INDEX command and it starts - it creates a **myDatabase.db-journal** file in the folder next to the .db file.

However, from "This PC" view of the hard drives I can see that disk C is getting drained (from 40GB, going 39 38 etc incrementally), ***myDatabase.db*** in drive D is not getting bigger.

I dont want SQLite to use C when it doesnt make sense for it do it as sqlite and .db file are in disk D.

Any suggestions why this is happening ?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: (Misread the question if you saw my first comment before I deleted it). Sqlite is probably using temporary files on the C drive as part of building the index. See https://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#temporary_file_storage_locations for how to specify a location besides the OS's default for those.

Comment: Also, you should (eventually) see the journal file growing, and then being deleted after the new index is committed to the database - that's when the .db file will grow, at the end.